# google-analytics v3 on Android pass a String

Tags: android, google-analytics

I need to track my `Android` app using `Google Analytics`

By now, I am able of tracking the `Activities`

```
 EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
```

But I would like to pass a custom String instead of the activity itself, something like `.setString("My activity")`

Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the screen as mentioned below :

```
    Tracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);

// This screen name value will remain set on the tracker and sent with
// hits until it is set to a new value or to null.
easyTracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "My Activity");

easyTracker.send(MapBuilder
    .createAppView()
    .build()
);
```

reference : [track screens](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/screens)

Answer (score 0):

create analytics.xml file in values.

and set activity for screen name...

**analytics.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID -->
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-47448579-1</string>

<!-- Enable automatic activity tracking -->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>


<integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">2</integer>

<!-- Enable automatic exception tracking -->
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

<!-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->
<string name="com.AnimalApp.LauncherActivity">Launcher Screen</string>
<string name="com.AnimalApp.AnimalActivity">Animal Screen</string>
<string name="com.AnimalApp.QuizActivity">Quiz Screen</string>
```